# Bad form to define a controller inside a model's class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

I have models defined as follows:

```
class Violation
class Violation::Action
class Violation::Attachment
```

Is it bad form to have the bare model class `Violation`? It's a bit worrying to me because I have controllers/authorizers/etc. defined as `Violation::ActionsController` and such. Does this mean my violation objects will be cluttered with things like `Action` and `ActionsController` that are defined in its class? Would it be better to change my bare violation class to `Violation::Report` and convert `Violation` to a module?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use Violation purely as namespacing and in that case I would make Violation a module. I can't see a reason why you would want to have Violation as a class.

Comment: Right now, it's an actual class used to make objects, as in `user has_many violations`. I'm wondering if I should change that to `user has_many violation_reports` to keep everything cleaner.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you design looks like, but it looks a bit confusing to me. The best advice I can give you is to read a book or two about Ruby programming. I can also recommend The Ruby Rouges podcast.